Could not build module errors in xcode
I am using Capacitor and have tried to integrate FireBase into my project also. I am receiving the following build errors:

I am using Xcode v15.4, and Pod version is v1.15.2
I have tried
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
pod deintegrate
pod update
pod install

And also cleaning the build folder and rebuilding.
My Podfile is as follows:
require_relative '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios/scripts/pods_helpers'

platform :ios, '13.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'

end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleTagManager'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      # config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      # config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      # config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is very much appreciated.

have you tried adding in the project , under Build Settings, the compile flag “-ObjC” in case is not yet present?

I had the same issues when build app with Xcode beta app. The fix was to rename beta app to Xcode.app.
